# How to get a value passed throuhgt url to a class Create View in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Salutations good people of stack overflow,
I read the docs and I been duckduckgoing this and I can't find and answer. I am pretty new to Django so if my approach is totally wrong please let me know. ^^

I am using Django 3.0 and I want to get a Primay Key of a model for a Post into a create view for a Comment Model with a foreign Key Post field, so that each Comment knows to which Post it belong in a one to many relationship. To accomplish I am defining the **template** as:

```
<a href="{% url 'comment_new' post.pk  %}">            
   <p class="text-center">Write a Comment</p>
</a>
```

In my **urls.py** I have:

```
urlpatterns = [      
        path('<int:post>/new', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment_new'),
        ]
```

and in my **views.py** I have:

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'Comment_new.html'
    fields = ('writing',)
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_object(self, **kwargs ):
        return models.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['post'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ''' Set the user which send the request as the form 'creator' '''
        form.instance.user = self.request.user

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I'm trying to access the post int by overwriting *get_object* with `return models.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['post'])`
, and the setting it to the comment model field in the *form_valid* with `form.instance.post = self.post` as I did with the users. But it does not seem to work any help I much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where is your models?

Comment: Hi Arakkal, I'm sorry.

Answer (score -1):

view.py

```
def create_view(request, pk):
    data = {}
    data['myModel'] = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', data)
```

my_template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'comment_new' myModel.id  %}">            
   <p class="text-center">Write a Comment</p>
</a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', create_view, name = 'url_create'),
]
```